# How to replace [USER_ID] with the actual uid in a offerwall iframe

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, uid

I'm making a GPT site (Get-Paid-to) where people get rewarded for completing offers, but I have problems adding the uid to the link of the offerwalls 
example:

```
<iframe src="https://example.com/api/?key=xxxxxx&uid=[USER_ID]" width="500" height="900" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

how do i replace `uid=[USER_ID]` with `uid=12345`?
thanks

Comment: What you have tried? Post your php code.

Comment: Where are you setting the scr url from javascript, and where is the user I'd coming from?

Comment: i guess what i'm looking for is how to replace USER_ID in just a link like
example.com/[USER_ID]

Comment: see my answer below, a simple string replace will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

With javascript you can do `str = str.replace("[USER_ID]", 123);`
Where str is the string containing uid=[USER_ID]
So string will then be uid=12345

So:

```
 <iframe id="iframeId" width="500" height="900" frameborder="0">
    <script>
        var str = "https://example.com/api/?key=xxxxxx&uid=[USER_ID]", 
            userId = 12345;

        document.getElementById('iframeId').src = str.replace("[USER_ID]", userId);
    </script>
```

will set result in

```
 <iframe id="iframeId" src="https://example.com/api/?key=xxxxxx&uid=12345" width="500" height="900" frameborder="0">
```

Comment: I'm using http://www.authpro.com which which gives me a register page and it almost give the user an ID
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.authpro.com/auth/casilo/?action=pp">
</script> this script have the user's info but i want to b able to extract the uid from it add to places that have uid='[USER_ID]'